# How to make the selector ":checked" work with "link_to" too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

When a user clicks this how can we automatically reload the page?

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: habit.current_habit_level.id }), remote: true, method: 'post', data: { confirm: 'You missed a committed day?' }, class: 'habit-check', id: 'remove_check' %>
```

`habit-check` triggers this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".habit-check").change(function () {
    var submitUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("submit-url");
    var deleteUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("delete-url");

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // We'd need to fix this line?
       $.ajax({ url: submitUrl, method: "POST" }).done(location.reload)
    } else {
       $.ajax({ url: deleteUrl, method: "DELETE" }).done(location.reload)
    }
  })
})
```

But this was designed to work when a checkbox was clicked. How can we get this to also work when a `link_to` button is clicked?

I envisioned something like this `if($(this).is(":checked && :clicked"))`, but I have little to no understanding of javascript, but I hope you get the idea :]

### UPDATE

I tried all the selectors from this page https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and they didn't work so I either did it wrong or the solution is more than just fixing a line.

### UPDATE AMIT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.remove-check').on('ajax:success', function() { location.reload() })
  $(".habit-check").change(function() {
    var submitUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("submit-url");
    var deleteUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("delete-url");

    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: submitUrl,
         method: "POST"
       })
       .done(function () {
         location.reload();
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: deleteUrl,
         method: "DELETE"
       })
       .done(function () {
         location.reload();
       });
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: In the future, you should follow the [airbnb javascript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript).

Comment: Do you want to check if ".habit-check" checkbox is checked or not when user is clicking "link to" button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `.habit-check` is no longer a checkbox, so your old code that handles the change event won't work.

So I assume you want to make this work with the link *instead* of a checkbox.
I also assume you're using Rails jquery-ujs (unobtrusive javascript with jQuery), which is the default nowadays.

You don't need to manually trigger an Ajax request with jQuery when you specify `remote: true` on the link or on a form. The ujs framework does it for you. So doing things like `data("submit-url")` to communicate between your markup and javascript code are unnecessary if the path is correctly defined in the `link_to` (which is your case). This is, again, the ujs framework's responsibility.

So, when the user clicks on a link or submits a form that has `remote: true`, the ujs framework will communicate with the server, and you can simply handle in javascript one of the Ajax events defined here:
https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

So in your case, doing this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.habit-check').on('ajax:success', function() { location.reload() })
})
```

Or this (if there is a chance your `.habit-check` link will be rendered by Javascript, e.g. as a response to an Ajax call):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('ajax:success', '.habit-check', function() { location.reload() })
})
```

Note: If you want to use the `ajax:success` event make sure your controller returns status 200. For whatever reason if the controller does `render text: 'hi'`, this won't work, so render a JSON back or simply `render nothing: true`.

**UPDATE - WITH CHECKBOX**

It seems like you'd like to call different controller actions based on the checkbox state. If this is the case, you can do it in javascript like you did, or follow my suggestion under "Different Controller Actions" below. If you're fine sending the checkbox state to one controller action and let the controller handle the "if checked then..", the code will be simpler:

In ERB:

```
<%= form_for @habit, remote: true, class: 'habit-form' do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :check, class: 'habit-check' %>
<% end %>
```

In Javascript:

```
$('.habit-check').on('change', function() { $('.habit-form').submit() })
$('.habit-form').on('ajax:success', function() { location.reload() })
```

In the controller:

```
def update
  habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
  if params[:habit][:check] == '1'
    # Do one thing
  else
    # Do another thing
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

Note that the code above makes the following assumptions:

- You have a class called `Habit`, which has an attribute called `check`.  If you don't want to have this check-box attribute as a db column, simply add it with `attr_accessor :check` in `Habit` class definition so that the `f.check_box :check` line works.
- The ERB template receives a `@habit` object of the class `Habit` that already exists in the db. In other words `@habit.new_record?` returns `false`. This would make the form communicate with the `update` action in the controller.

**DIFFERENT CONTROLLER ACTIONS**

If you want to call different controller actions based on the check box state while avoiding the `$.ajax` calls (which I personally think is cleaner), you can render two different forms and have the javascript select which one to submit.

In ERB:

```
<%= form_for @habit, url: destroy_habit_path, method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'destroy-form redirect-after-success' %>
<%= form_for Habit.new, url: habits_path, method: :post remote: true, class: 'create-form redirect-after-success' %>
```

In javascript:

```
$('.habit-check').on('change', function() { 
  var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var formClass = isChecked ? '.create-form' : '.destroy-form';
  $(formClass).submit() 
});
$('.redirect-after-success').on('ajax:success', function() { location.reload() });
```

And note that you can also add the `redirect-after-success` class to your `.remove-check` link, so the javascript code above will support with no changes your link from our initial discussion.

Comment: Thank you Amit for going above and beyond with your awesome explanation! I updated my question with your code and with mine so that the link AND the checkbox work. It works perfectly now in my browser. I'll give you the bounty, but I was just wondering if you saw my edit as the most effective way to do this. Thanks again!